# How to upload images to a server in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

It won't work, how to send an image from an iOS Swift app to my PHP server?

```
@IBAction func upload(sender: UIButton) {

    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img.image, 90)
   // println(imageData)
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.i35.club.tw/old_tree/test/uplo.php")
    //let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    //var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)
    request.HTTPBody = imageData
    // set data
    //var dataString = "adkjlkajfdadf"
    //let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    //request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData


    //

    request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    //
    // set content length

    //NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

    let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("API Response: \(results)")
}

//take photo
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {


    var selectedImage : UIImage = image
     img.image = selectedImage
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage, nil, nil, nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 29):

I have taken the photo by user's choice and written code for swift 2 and iOS9

```
    func imageUploadRequest(imageView imageView: UIImageView, uploadUrl: NSURL, param: [String:String]?) {

        //let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.103/upload.photo/index.php");

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:uploadUrl);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

        request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)

        //myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

        let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,
            completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if let data = data {

                    // You can print out response object
                    print("******* response = \(response)")

                    print(data.length)
                    // you can use data here

                    // Print out reponse body
                    let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

                    let json =  try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    print("json value \(json)")

                    //var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        //self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        //self.imageView.image = nil;
                    });

                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error.description)
                }
        })
        task.resume()


    }


    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(imageDataKey)
        body.appendString("\r\n")

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    }

}// extension for impage uploading

extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        appendData(data!)
    }
}
```

---

--------- following code for the php side

```
<?php

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$userId = $_POST["userId"];

$target_dir = "media";

if(!file_exists($target_dir))
{
mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) 
{
echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

} else {

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

}
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for days.  Just came across your code and it works like a charm.  Thanks!!

Comment: @VinodJoshi can you do the same for node js and express backed ?

Answer (score 11):

To upload image with parameters use this code,

```
 // Your method to upload image with parameters to server.     

func uploadImageOne(){
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)

    if imageData != nil{
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"Enter Your URL")!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
      //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var body = NSMutableData.alloc()

        // Title
         body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Hello World".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)

        // Image
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_img\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



        request.HTTPBody = body


        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("returnString \(returnString)")

    }


}
```

Comment: Any image I try comes up as a corrupted file when i try to view it

Comment: @ inVINCEable I have done this using the same above code. Please check your php service, and image is of multi type and octet strem.

Comment: My php service is fine, i ended up switching to SRWebClient and it worked perfectly

Comment: @ inVINCEable  Glad that your task has been done. And thanks for telling about  SRWebClient.

Comment: -1 for using `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest`. Use NSURLSession instead and don't send synchronous network requests!

Answer (score 8):

My updated code for **Swift 3**

```
func uploadImage() {
    let url = URL(string: "YOUR SERVER URL");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var retreivedImage: UIImage? = nil
    //Get image
    do {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let readData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "file://\(documentsPath)/myImage")!)
        retreivedImage = UIImage(data: readData)
        addProfilePicView.setImage(retreivedImage, for: .normal)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error while opening image")
        return
    }

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(retreivedImage!, 1)
    if (imageData == nil) {
        print("UIImageJPEGRepresentation return nil")
        return
    }

    let body = NSMutableData()
    body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_token\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "api_token")! as NSString)).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_img\"; filename=\"testfromios.jpg\"\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(imageData!)
    body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

    request.httpBody = body as Data

    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let data = data {
           // do what you want in success case   
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

And PHP side code you can take from [@VinodJoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32904778/4380917) answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the blogpost of Sergey Kargopolov (http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/) and his video (https://youtu.be/HqxeyS961Uk) here is my code that worked perfectly in Swift 5.
It will upload a picture to the directory specified in the php script (further down) and it will name the picture according to the imgKey given. In my example, it will upload the imageToUpload of myImageUploadRequest to the directory "wp-content/Images". The param dictionary is not necessarily needed. This could very well be written more efficiently but maybe it is a start for someone :)

```
func myImageUploadRequest(imageToUpload: UIImage, imgKey: String) {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://yourdomain/uploadPicture.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let param = [
        "firstName"  : "name",
        "lastName"    : "name",
        "userId"    : "42"
    ]

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let imageData = imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    if imageData == nil  {
        return
    }

    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary, imgKey: imgKey) as Data

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error!)")
                return
            }

            //print response
            //print("response = \(response!)")

            // print reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("response data = \(responseString!)")

        }

        task.resume()
    }




func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String, imgKey: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "\(imgKey).jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }

}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

The server sided php (PHP/7.3.18) code:

```
<?php

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$userId = $_POST["userId"];

$target_dir = "wp-content/Images";

if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
    mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {

    echo json_encode([
    "Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
    "Status" => "OK",
    "userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
    ]);

} 
else {

    echo json_encode([
    "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
    "Status" => "Error",
    "userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
    ]);

}

?>
```

Example console output:

```
response data = {
"Message":"The file 9B862D73-9F0B-4DD3-8FBB-452AEF2FE1CF.jpg has been uploaded.",
"Status":"OK",
"userId":"17"}
```

Comment: You DEFINITELY shouldn't be using "NSUrl"... or "NS-anything" for that matter. Especially if you're on Swift 5.  You can just use "URL(string: link)".  The guie you linked to is from 2015... so it's terribly outdated.

Comment: This is an underappreciated comment.

Answer (score 3):

I have made function for Block method which is easy to use and this is class function so you can use anywhere in your project for example make

```
MVCServer.swift
```

NSObject class and

```
import Alamofire
```

and then write this function in this class

```
 func postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl strURL: String,withParam postParam: Dictionary<String, Any>,withImages imageArray:NSMutableArray,completion:@escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ response:NSDictionary) -> Void)
{

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in

        // Here is your Image Array
        for (imageDic) in imageArray
        {
            let imageDic = imageDic as! NSDictionary

            for (key,valus) in imageDic
            {
                MultipartFormData.append(valus as! Data, withName:key as! String,fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
        }

        // Here is your Post paramaters
        for (key, value) in postParam
        {
            MultipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: strURL, method: .post) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                if response.response?.statusCode == 200
                {
                    let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary

                    completion(true,json!);
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(false,[:]);
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)

            completion(false,[:]);
        }

    }
}
```

Now Call this Function

```
var ImageArray : NSMutableArray!

// Here is your post parameter 
var parameters: [String:Any] = ["user_master_id" : “56”,
                                        "first_name": “Jignesh”,
                                        "last_name" : “Mayani”,
                                        "email": “TestEmail@gmail.com”]
// Here is your image is in DATA formate don’t send as UIImage formate       
let ImageDic = ["profile_image" : imageData!]

// Here you can pass multiple image in array i am passing just one 
ImageArray = NSMutableArray(array: [ImageDic as NSDictionary])

MVCServer().postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl: "write Your URL here", withParam: parameters, withImages: ImageArray) { (isSuccess, response) in
      // Your Will Get Response here   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func upload(sender: UIButton) {
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img.image, 90)
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.i35.club.tw/old_tree/test/uplo.php")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = NSData.dataWithData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageData))
        
    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

    let results = NSString(data: reply!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("API Response: \(results)")
}
```

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift)

Comment: how is this done if there are multiple parameters to be sent up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006290/uploading-image-in-swift-with-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to take a look at: https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient

Sample function that worked for me:

```
func uploadImage(image:UIImage) {
  let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)
  SRWebClient.POST("http://www.example.com/upload/")
    .data(imageData, fieldName:"photo", data: ["foo":"bar","baz":"qux"])
    .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
        // process success response
    },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        // process failure response
    })
}
```

You’ll notice that the above code is a slightly adjusted version of the snippets on the Swift-SRWebClient Github page. I’ve replaced `NSData.dataWithData` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` as the former is deprecated.

Also, don’t forget to drag `SRWebClient.swift` into your project folder, otherwise this won’t work :)

Comment: @VincentvanLeeuwen this isn't working for me... how do I send up parameters? I included them in the data but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Here is a more elaborate version of what I did: http://blog.vincentleeuwen.com/uploading-an-image-with-swift-and-django-rest-api-framework

Comment: @bashan Got it working in Swift 2. Check out my fork: https://github.com/sshadmand/Swift-SRWebClient

Answer (score 0):

This is great, I've been trying to pass an image using REST for a while and coouldn't format it just right and kept getting timeout errors.  Using createBodyWithParameters I was able to make it work.

Here's the Swift 3 version of the code:

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: UIImage, boundary: String) -> Data {
  var body = Data();

  if parameters != nil {
     for (key, value) in parameters! {
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
     }
  }

  let filename = "user-profile.jpg"

  let mimetype = "image/jpg"

  body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
  body.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageDataKey, 1)!)
  //body.appendData(imageDataKey)
  body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

  body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

  return body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look on that simple explanation:

> [Form data and multipart uploads with URLRequest](https://newfivefour.com/swift-form-data-multipart-upload-URLRequest.html)

Also, to keep code up to date you can replace `NSMutableData` on `Data`. So your final code will be looks like:

```
func createHttpBody(parameters: [String: String]? = nil, _ boundary: String, data: Data, mimeType: String, filename: String) -> Data {
    var body = Data()

    let boundaryPrefix = "--\(boundary)\r\n"

    if let parameters = parameters {

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append(boundaryPrefix)
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.append("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    body.append(boundaryPrefix)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(data)
    body.append("\r\n")
    body.append("--".appending(boundary.appending("--")))

    return body
}
```

And updated extension for `Data` to use `append` method:

```
extension Data {

    mutating func append(_ string: String) {

        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GH0yMPvQFU) and check [source code](https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/URLSessionMPFD) for that tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

> **request.httpMethod = "POST"** is important for upload long string or blob

```
func imageUpload(imageData:String){       
 var request:NSMutableURLRequest!
        let param:String = "image=\(imageData)" // image data should be here
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "www.pickmyoffers.com")!)// use your upload php file link and parameter "example.com/upload.php?image=\(imageData)"
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        request.httpBody = param.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {data,response,error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(responseString!)
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Where did you use "imageData"? Why param is empty string?

Answer (score -2):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

See my Code in this blog for **Upload image to server in Swift**

https://markingios.blogspot.com/2018/09/upload-image-to-server-in-swift.html

Call this function like :  uploadImage()

```
func uploadImage(){

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage!, 1.0)//Replace your image

if imageData != nil{
   var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string:urlString)! as URL)//Send your URL here
   print(request)

   request.httpMethod = "POST"

   let boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
   let contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
   //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
   request.addValue(contentType as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   var body = Data()

   body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
   body.append(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n").data
                        (using:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
   body.append("Hello".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)


   body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
   body.append(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"image.jpg\"\\r\n").data
                       (using:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!) //Here replace your image name and file name
   body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
   body.append(imageData!)
   body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

   request.httpBody = body

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil      
       else { // check for fundamental networking error
       print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
       SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, message: "\(String(describing: error!.localizedDescription))")
       return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 500 {
        SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, message: "Server Error")
    } else if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
         print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
         print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
    }

    //This can print your response in string formate        
    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
     //            let dictionary = data
     //            print("dictionary = \(dictionary)")
     print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString!))")

     do {
         self.response3 = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject])!
         print(self.response3)

         if (((self.response3["Response"] as? [String : Any])?["status"]) as! String == "SUCCESS") {
               let message = (self.response3["Response"] as? [String : Any])?["message"] as? String
                   SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view:self, message: message)
          } else {
                let message = (self.response3["Response"] as? [String : Any])?["message"] as? String
                    SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view:self, message: message)
                }

      } catch let error as NSError {
           print(error)
           print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
   }

    task.resume()

 }


}
```

Comment: Do not specify a hardcoded value for the `boundary`. Use dynamically-generated value like `NSUUID().uuidString` instead.