# How to send image file from ios application to mysql database through REST A

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

I need to create a method to send a images to the database through JSON/REST API, i know how to send data to the database like passwords, long texts and etc... But i need to know how to send a blob to the database or an method to send the image as binary.

Someone can help me???

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the Swift API Reference?

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27902593/5999975

Comment: Take a look at Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: Thanks Tung Fan!