# how to upload image,pdf,audio,video and any file system from iphone local memory to server(API)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I have to upload any kind of file system from local phone memory to API given.Is there a simple way to that please help.

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you have tried.. So that we can determine exactly what is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload images to a server in iOS with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335656/how-to-upload-images-to-a-server-in-ios-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire library.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    if let parameters = parameters {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let value = value as? String {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }else if let _image = value as? UIImage, let image = _image.resized(toWidth: 500) {
                if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                    multipartFormData.append(jpegData, withName: key, fileName: "post.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }else if let pngData = image.pngData() {
                    multipartFormData.append(pngData, withName: key, fileName: "post.png", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
            }else {
                multipartFormData.append(Data(from: value), withName: key)
            }
        }
    }
}, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: urlString, method: method, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            if let responseData = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                completion(responseData, response.data, response.result)
            }else if let responseData = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                completion(responseData as NSDictionary, response.data, response.result)
            }else {
                completion([:], nil, response.result)
            }
        }
        break
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        completion([:], nil, .failure(encodingError))
        break
    }
})
```

Comment: can it work for any type of file,or can it works in objective c.@AMIT MONDOL.