# How can I wait for the result of the POST call in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm using the google api for ios for signing in to the mobile app (taken from here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth
They are showing there how to use objective-c to make a post request to the backend server and as a result - get the info if the token is valid or not.

I established my backend server properly and it verifies if the token is good or not (and it returns the status `200` or `401`. Now I just need to send the token from the app to my server and based on its result validate the user or not.

I found this answer about making post requests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148/4662074

and following this example I coded it as follows:

```
// [START signin_handler]
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            print("!!!! TOKEN !!!! "+user.authentication.idToken)

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://mywebserver.com:3000/auth/token")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "id_token="+user.authentication.idToken
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                }

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")


                print("Signed in as a user: "+user.profile.name)

            }
            task.resume()

            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
                self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
}
// [END signin_handler]
```

Ok, in this case right after making a call to the webservice I'm switching the view to the main page of the app:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
                    self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
                }
```

But since I'm doing it right after `task.resume()` - that means I'm never waiting for the result from the webservice and even if it states `401` - user is still signed it. I tried to put that piece of code above the `task.resume()` but then I'm getting error:

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
```

So how can I include the answer from my webservice during the logging in process and if the status is `200` - then switch the view to my `TabController`? (and in other cases for example ask the user to log in again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell, don't wait.

The request works asynchronously, so instantiate you controller in the completion block on success. To avoid the `auto layout engine` message you have to do that on the main thread.

```
       ...
       print("Signed in as a user: "+user.profile.name)

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
            self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
          }
       }
     }
     task.resume()
   } else { ... }
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, that makes sense, but I see I have to do it only if the status is 200 - can you tell me, based on my code, how can I check it?

Comment: Just add a `return` statement when the response code is checked like in the `guard` expression.

Comment: sorry if that's a tedious question, I added `return` just after `print("response = \(response)")` but now when I want to include `httpStatus` in an if statement later on I'm getting `use of unresolved value httpStatus` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `guard let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 else { print .. return } `