# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Ok, I am now starting with iOS development and currently playing with NSData using Obj-C. Recently I'm using the URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData method to get NSData using **HTTP POST request**. The server will be responding a JSON object containing a JSON array.

***Something interesting is that when the response data is too large the NSLog part will print out: "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format"***. Below is the function:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSError *error;
    // get data from NSData into NSDict
    NSDictionary *searchData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSArray *test = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"what: %@", mdict);
    NSLog(@"received data length: %@", [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"json error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Just wondering if anyone knows the potential reason causing this problem ??

[Update]

Well, an alternative to solve this problem might be using NSString for data storage. But would have to parse it by myself. I would prefer using NSDictionary though.

Comment: How did you determine that the data is too large? And how large is too large?

Comment: I invoked the `[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);` function to calculate the length in KB.

Comment: And what did it tell you?

Comment: when the data is around 200 bytes, I can correctly store it in a NSDictionary; but unfortunately not for data with 21 KB

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])` Try that and see what you get. If the data is truly JSON, it should be printable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beginner problem: didReceiveData is called when *some* of the data has arrived, before the data is complete. Read the documentation of didReceiveData, which explains what you need to do. You are trying to parse incomplete data. That won't work.

And when you are handling JSON data, you should *never* involve any NSString objects, except possibly to log data.

Comment: I believe this is correct, however to actually solve the issue requires an `NSMutableData` instance variable that is appended to in `didReceiveData` and finally parsed as JSON when `didCompleteWithError` is called.

Answer (score 3):

In my case i was hitting POST Method instead of GET. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

At first point you should check if the response received from the API is a *valid JSON*, can be check by online validators like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com). If this is a vaid json, then you are good to go.

Further more you should evaluate the `error` object on every step when you get it to see which parsing of data cause this problem like:

```
    NSError *error;
    // get data from NSData into NSDict
    NSDictionary *searchData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"json error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSArray *test = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];


    NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"what: %@", mdict);

    NSLog(@"received data length: %@", [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"json error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Also, as you said that:

> The server will be responding a JSON object containing a JSON array.

Are you sure it is returning NS(Mutable)Dictionary ?? Try printing it like this:

```
    id response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"json error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"json data : %@", response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if the data is kind of josn ,you can

```
NSDictionary *dict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

**or**

```
[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])
```

,so that you will be get nsdictionary or nsstring data, if you cannot parse it by yourself ,you can user jsonModel tranlte to model .

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with your json data I have experienced the same. You have to serialize your json data like this below written code

```
NSDictionary *dict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

If you are populating json data from  data base u have to use Nsarray.
Hope this will help  you .

Comment: I did try this one, it's not this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method

Comment: please follow this link .hope it will work .if u facing problem to convert swift to objective c to swift https://objectivec2swift.com.

Comment: it is solved now. Thank you!
It really was simply a problem accessing the data before the query ended.