# Swift3: How to load data from external database using PHP and Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am trying to load the table by fetching data from the external database using PHP. I have the script on the server, and able to fetch the data. I'm trying to get help and understand the logic, but still I cant get it.

At the moment, I have only set up my tableview but there is not data.

Please let me know how can I fetch the data.

Thanks

code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var group = [Group]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return myarray.count
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
       // cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Code:(how can I get the data displayed on the table view)?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//let myarray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]



var group = [Group]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.myurl/myfile.php")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    }

    task.resume()        
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableview.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return myarray.count
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
   // cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: As mentioned in your question that you are using PHP to connect with external database, You need to create web services to fetch data from database. These web services will be called from mobile app to fetch data. Once receive data using webservice, then you can display that in app.

Comment: *... and able to fetch the data*. Then show the code you are using to fetch the data.

Comment: @Surjeet  how can i use this web service? I do remember reading about it, but couldnt understand at all

Comment: @SarahMalik You can use NSUrlSession to call web services or some third party library like AFNetworking, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire as well to call web services.

Comment: @Surjeet , well I found this online [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method) and I am able to see the desire output. How do I use the data to display on the table

Comment: You need to create  a array from data received from web service to display on a table and within   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell func you can display data on labels.

Comment: @Surjeet , I have just posted my new code and I am not able to find relevant information and its just confuses me alot :( . If you see my second part of my code, and let me know how can I do this. Thanks....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147680/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-surjeet).

Comment: @Surjeet, I am continuing this discussion in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a array or Dictionary based on your response using below code

You need to pass string to these func which you are using within print statement.

**If response return as a dictionary**

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Get array from dictionary to bind with tableview.

**If response return as an Array**

```
func convertToArray(text: String) -> [Any]? {
        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Any]
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Then bind data from this array to tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tutorial for load data on `iOS` via Web Services from `iOS` side and create Web Services from Server side.

**Create a simple PHP/MySQL web service for iOS app.**

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

**To call that Web Service from iOS app**

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service