# JSONSerialization makes incorrect JSON object. Swift

Tags: node.js, json, swift

I'm creating an iOS app that connects to a NodeJS server. The get method works fine but the POST method has problems.

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: "http://localhost:3000/register")
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
let info: [String:Any] = ["username": "username", "password":"username", "email":"username@username.com"]
do {
    let jsonInfo = try 
    JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: info, options[])
    urlRequest.httpBody = jsonInfo
} catch {
    print("ERROR")
    return
}
```

The request gets sent but something goes wrong with JSONSerialization because this is the JSON data that the server gets:
`{'{"email":"username@username.com","username":"username","password":"username"}': '' }`

This is what I'm going for:
`{"email":"username@username.com","username":"username","password":"username"}`

This is part of the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var allowMethods = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE');
next();
}
http.createServer(app).listen(3001);
console.log("Server started");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(allowMethods);

const _ = require('lodash');
let b = _.pick(req.body, ['username', 'password', 'email']);
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'd like to avoid using alamofire if possible. I've tried changing the format of the dictionary but always turns out as:

```
{ 'the whole dictionary is the key': ''}
```

I've also tried using pretty print and this was the result:

```
{ '{\n  "email" : "username@username.com",\n  "username" : "username",\n  "password" : "username"\n}': '' }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

I tried Mike Taverne's suggestions.
I changed the server code to use this instead:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

But I receive an empty body from the simulator.
I also added these to the swift code:

```
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

But the server also receives an empty body and by empty body I mean the data I'm trying to send is received as empty by the server. When I check the httpBody the data is there but for some reason the server doesn't receive it.

Comment: You can use Codable for Json parsing. its easy to use and flexiable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the data itself. Instead of forcing it to pass JSON I passed it as a string encoded using UTF8

```
let dataString = "username=username&password=username&email=username@username.com"
urlRequest.httpBody = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
```

I got the answer by using the method in this post:
[HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Swift code is fine. When I did this in a playground:

```
print(String(data: urlRequest.httpBody!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

It printed:

```
{"username":"username","password":"username","email":"username@username.com"}
```

I'm not an expert on body-parser, but I think that instead of this:

```
bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})
```

You should be using this:

```
bodyParser.json([options]) //not sure which options exactly you need
```

You may need to set `Content-Type: application/json` header as well. Refer to the [body-parser documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for more info.

Comment: I tried using bodyParser.json() with the different options as well as setting the headers like so urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept"). I mixed and matched the changes but every time I put in any of those changes my server receives an empty body {}.