# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1. swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, api, nsjsonserialization

I got response from api via postman

```
{
"status": "1",
"error": false,
"message": "Your order has been placed successfully"
}
```

I called api and pass the params which required to call api. The code is giving an error  "Invalid value around character 1."

```
    let urlsContainer = UrlsContainer()
    let url = URL(string: urlsContainer.allotRunnerAPI)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)&pincode=\(pincode)&select_address=\(select_address)&store_id=\(store_id)"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
    return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
    return
    }
```

The code should execute the do block of code

```
do {
    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(parsedData)
    }
```

but now because of some problem in code it is executing catch block of code

```
 catch let error {
    print(error)
    }
   })
  task.resume()
```

I am not able to find the problem in my code to resolve the error

Comment: `print(String(data:data, encoding:.utf8)!)`. I guess the response is not JSON.

Comment: @vadian yeah printing html tags any solution?

Comment: Your syntax (key-value pairs separated by ampersand characters) is for GET requests. For POST requests you have to send a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian ok thanks for share it actually I don't know it before but still it has same problem

Comment: @SanjayMishra - this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/26364914/1042817

Comment: Please check the response of html tags carefully, you may find the reason of error, also check if your service api need token and you may forget to send it, I faced same problem and the reason was forgetting send the token.

Comment: @Hosny Thanks for response ok

Answer (score 0):

use `[String:String]` to send data to api

```
let params = ["user_id":user_id,
"pincode":pincode,"select_address":select_address,
"store_id":store_id]
let data = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

post this data as your body

Comment: Never *prettyPrint* JSON which is being sent to a server. The server doesn't care for legibility at all. Omit the `options` parameter