# How to pass two or many values in WKWebView's HTTP request body?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I want to pass two values in HTTP request body. I try to do it like this but it isn't working. can anyone help me?

```
   guard let url = URL(string: "*****") else { return }
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let post: String = "cardId=\(viewModel.getCardId())&requestId=\(viewModel.getRequestId())"

    if let postData: Data = post.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: true) {
        request.httpBody = postData
        webView.load(request as URLRequest)
    }
```

Comment: every time I get a 400 status code. I do something bad

Comment: Unrelated, but avoid using ((NS)Mutable)Stuff when `Stuff` is availble. So `NSMutableURLRequest` => `URLRequest` (you won't need later the `as URLRequest`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148/718925