# Post method generic codable API response not coming properly in swift

Tags: json, swift, web-services, parameters, codable

I have created `APINetworkManagerAll` here i have created `serviceCall` and calling that in `ViewController`. here `postGenericCall2()` is called and response also coming but my given `param` values not coming instead it says nil why? i am passing same values in postmn then response coming properly? where am i wrong? guide me please.

```swift
struct RequestObjectAll {
    var params: [String: Any]? = nil
    var method: HTTPMethod
    var urlPath: String
    var isTokenNeeded: Bool
    var isLoaderNeed: Bool = false
    var isErrorNeed: Bool = false
    var vc: UIViewController?
}

class APINetworkManagerAll: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = APINetworkManagerAll()
    
    fileprivate override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func serviceCall<T: Decodable>(requestObject: RequestObjectAll, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        if requestObject.isLoaderNeed {
            requestObject.vc?.showLoader()
        }
        
        guard let url = URL(string: requestObject.urlPath) else {
            if requestObject.isLoaderNeed {
                requestObject.vc?.hideLoader()
            }
            completion(.failure(NetworkError.invalidURL))
            return
        }
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = requestObject.method.rawValue
        
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestObject.params ?? ["" : ""], options: []) else {
                        return
                    }
        urlRequest.httpBody = httpBody
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, _, error in
            if requestObject.isLoaderNeed {
                requestObject.vc?.hideLoader()
            }
            
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(response))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            } else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "YourDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No data received"])
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

And

```swift
func postGenericCall2(){        
    let param = ["name": "john",
                 "job": "AAA"
    ] 
    
    let requestObject = RequestObjectAll(
        params: param,
        method: .post,
        urlPath: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
        isTokenNeeded: false,
        isLoaderNeed: true,
        vc: self
    )
    APINetworkManagerAll.sharedInstance.serviceCall(requestObject: requestObject) { (result: Result<PostGenModelSmall, Error>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            // Handle a successful response
            print("result of post service call.....: \(response)")
            
        case .failure(let error):
            // Handle the error
            print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
        }
    }        
}

struct PostGenModelSmall: Codable {
    let name: String
    let job: String
    let id: String
    let createdAt: String
}
```

error:

> Error decoding JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil) ("name").", underlyingError: nil))

**EDIT:** if i write service call like this then i am getting response as postman. so is there any issue in above my `APINetworkManagerAll` > `serviceCall` method while adding `urlRequest.httpBody = httpBody` body to urlRequest?

```
func postServiceCall(){
    let params: [String : Any] = ["name": "john", "job": "AAA"]
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        print(response!)
        do {
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String : Any]
            print("post data with response....\(json)")
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
}
```

o/p:

> post data with response....Optional(["id": 582, "createdAt": 2024-03-12T06:28:51.904Z, "job": AAA, "name": john])

Comment: The error message seems obvious. There is no property with the name "name" in the JSON returned. Try to print the response string with `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` right before you try to decode it and add the output to your question.

Comment: The type you are trying to decode into seems to have nothing in common with the json response. Are you accessing the wrong endpoint or misread the documentation or what is going on?

Comment: You are trying to decode `PostGenModelSmall` but this is not `at all` what you get from
 your server response. As mentioned, there is no `name` in the response, also there is no `job` and no `createdAt` either. Copy and paste the response json data into https://app.quicktype.io/ and the correct code will be generated for you.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine – The response type is correct for well-formed `POST` request. (Maybe you were looking at the `GET` request, whose response is a different kettle of fish; I made that mistake when I first looked at this question.) The problem is that the malformed `POST` request in the question generates a malformed response.

Comment: yes, you could be right. I just typed this in my browser to check things, https://reqres.in/api/users?name=john&job=AAA

Comment: @Swift – in your revised question, you are asking why your new rendition works, when the old one doesn’t; it is because your new snippet is setting the `Content-Type` header, whereas your original one did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, we should examine the response and make sure it is what we expected.

In this case, your JSON response to the `POST` request with JSON body is very strange. It contains:

```json
{
    "{\"name\": \"john\",\"job\": \"AAA\"}": "",
    "id": "100",
    "createdAt": "2024-03-11T20:37:25.020Z"
}
```

It looks like it was not expecting JSON in the body of the request. It is a question of what your backend is expecting. In your case, as your particular backend appears to accept both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` requests, you have two options:

1. You can set the `Content-Type` header of your request to let it know that the payload is JSON:

   ```swift
   request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   do {
       urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestObject.params ?? ["" : ""])
   } catch {
       completion(.failure(error))       // note, if you are going to exit, make sure to call completion handler
       return
   }
   ```
2. You can change the request to be an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request:

   ```swift
   // for the sake of clarity, you might want to set `Content-Type`
   // even though it defaults to x-www-form-urlencoded
   //
   // request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

   request.httpBody = Data("name=joe&job=AAA".utf8)
   ```

   Note, your particular server defaults

But, as your code stands, the request is not well-formed (in the absence of a `Content-Type` header of `application/json`, it assumes it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but the body is JSON), and not only did the backend not detect this, but it also returned a nonsensical response.

You really should fix the backend so that a malformed request returns a non-200 response, e.g., a 400 status code. And, often (in dev environments, at least) we would include a body (with some consistent “error” JSON payload) in that response that indicates the nature of the error, namely that `name` and `job` were not successfully parsed from the request. The specifics of how the backend should validate requests and report errors is beyond the scope of this question, but FYI.

---

If we replace the `httpBody` with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` sort of payload, like below, it worked correctly:

```swift
request.httpBody = Data("name=john&job=AAA".utf8)
```

It generated the response you were looking for:

```json
{
    "name":"john",
    "job":"AAA",
    "id":"859",
    "createdAt":"2024-03-11T20:29:44.446Z"
}
```

---

Note, if your request must be in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, make sure to property escape the values. See [HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26364914/1271826) if doing this manually. Or use a framework, like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), which will greatly simply the creation of well-formed `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests.

---

As an unrelated observation, I might suggest defining `createdAt` to be a `Date`:

```swift
struct PostGenModelSmall: Codable {
    let name: String
    let job: String
    let id: String
    let createdAt: Date
}
```

And, then when decoding, set a date formatter for the `JSONDecoder`:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
        
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let response = try decoder.decode(PostGenModelSmall.self, from: data)
```

Then, it will parse the date for you.

---

By the way, you mentioned that you have a working Postman request. In Postman, you can tap on the `</>` button, choose “Swift – URLSession” and it will show you a simple example of what the Swift code might look like:

[image: postman screen snapshot - code generation]

Like most auto-generated code, the code is not great, but it will give you a starting place from which you can start to compare and contrast against your code. In this case, note the `httpBody` of the request (and the setting of the `Content-Type` header of the request, which is not required, but is best practice).

Obviously, when you do this, your request might be a little different, but hopefully it illustrates how you can use Postman features to see what the Swift code might look like.