# How to add an extra POST parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsurlrequest

This is the code that upload an image but I have to send another POST parameter to know who is the person that upload the image.

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://www.theweb.com/api/img.php")!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
        //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPBody = dataMeData

        var body = NSMutableData.alloc()


        // Image
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"\(me)\"\\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        request.HTTPBody = body

        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("returnString \(returnString!)")
```

I have tried to add the following:

```
body.appendData(thePersonWhoUpload) ---> in NSData encoding it in UTF8 but it doesn't work.
```

So the final question is: how can I send another POST parameter which contains a name?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What is the server expecting and what does it receive?

Comment: @wain In php I write echo $_POST['theNameOfTheNewPostParameter'] but it gives me anything, just the imageData.

Comment: just curious why you don't use NSURLSession or AFNetwoking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to used multipart/form-data to upload image with parameter
 here is a stack overflow  link [Upload image with parameters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift)

Or u can used third party library like [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way... include uploaded person name in post body only.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UploadedBy=%@ &",username];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 

postData.appendData(imageData);

body.appendData(imageData);
```