# Upload image with multipart form-data iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, file-upload, multipartform-data

i am having a problem with uploading image with multipart-form

here is my code i used from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift)

```
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var body = NSMutableData()

    if self.img.image != nil {
        var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img.image)

        if imageData != nil {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendData(imageData!)
            body.appendString("\r\n")
        }

    }

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
    request.HTTPBody = body
```

then i use NSURLSession to apply the request

the server says that i didn't choose image to upload i only want to upload the image for now

do i have to use paths of images to upload any image or it's data is enough?

do i miss any thing , any help to understand this ?

Answer (score 55):

No Need to use any library for upload images using multipart request.

**Swift 4.2**

```
func uploadImage(paramName: String, fileName: String, image: UIImage) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://api-host-name/v1/api/uploadfile/single")

    // generate boundary string using a unique per-app string
    let boundary = UUID().uuidString

    let session = URLSession.shared

    // Set the URLRequest to POST and to the specified URL
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    // Set Content-Type Header to multipart/form-data, this is equivalent to submitting form data with file upload in a web browser
    // And the boundary is also set here
    urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var data = Data()

    // Add the image data to the raw http request data
    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append(image.pngData()!)

    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    // Send a POST request to the URL, with the data we created earlier
    session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: data, completionHandler: { responseData, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: .allowFragments)
            if let json = jsonData as? [String: Any] {
                print(json)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

If you have any header to add, you can add it via `urlRequest.setValue` method.

Source: https://fluffy.es/upload-image-to-server/

Comment: The final `\r\n` after the close-delimiter (`\r\n--\(boundary)--`) is optional.

Comment: How to add extra json input along with this?

Comment: I change it from  data.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) to data.append("Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!) for my end to workable this coe

Comment: Hi! Could you please say paramName is base64String?

Answer (score 39):

My version that 100% works. Maybe it will help you.

```
let url = "http://server/upload"
let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fullPath)
let data: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1)

sendFile(url, 
    fileName:"one.jpg", 
    data:data, 
    completionHandler: completionHandler:{
        (result:Bool, isNoInternetConnection:Bool) -> Void in

            // ...     
            NSLog("Complete: \(result)")
    }
)


func sendFile(
    urlPath:String,
    fileName:String,
    data:NSData,
    completionHandler: (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void){
        
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        
        request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        
        let boundary = generateBoundary()
        let fullData = photoDataToFormData(data,boundary:boundary,fileName:fileName)
        
        request1.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary,
            forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // REQUIRED!
        request1.setValue(String(fullData.length), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        
        request1.HTTPBody = fullData
        request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = false
        
        let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
        
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            request1,
            queue: queue,
            completionHandler:completionHandler)
}

// this is a very verbose version of that function
// you can shorten it, but i left it as-is for clarity
// and as an example
func photoDataToFormData(data:NSData,boundary:String,fileName:String) -> NSData {
    var fullData = NSMutableData()
    
    // 1 - Boundary should start with --
    let lineOne = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
    fullData.appendData(lineOne.dataUsingEncoding(
        NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    // 2
    let lineTwo = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"
    NSLog(lineTwo)
    fullData.appendData(lineTwo.dataUsingEncoding(
        NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    // 3
    let lineThree = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
    fullData.appendData(lineThree.dataUsingEncoding(
        NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    // 4
    fullData.appendData(data)
    
    // 5
    let lineFive = "\r\n"
    fullData.appendData(lineFive.dataUsingEncoding(
        NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    // 6 - The end. Notice -- at the start and at the end
    let lineSix = "--" + boundary + "--\r\n"
    fullData.appendData(lineSix.dataUsingEncoding(
        NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    return fullData
}
```

Comment: thanks you for with answer!)
I just add in solution 
request1.setValue("gzip, deflate", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding") 
and my image did uploaded

Comment: Wow.  Something I'm thinking, what if you ALSO have to send text input fields?

Comment: What is generateBoundary?

Comment: @Priyal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

Comment: For future cases: This is done so much easier with frameworks like [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya).

Comment: @Anthony, I am able to send file to server. Now I want to send some description too with the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: so `filename` is required, or the upload will be ignored. The filename can be filled with whatever (not the actual filename).

Answer (score 9):

```
import Foundation

struct MultipartFormDataRequest {
    private let boundary: String = UUID().uuidString
    var httpBody = NSMutableData()
    let url: URL
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    func addTextField(named name: String, value: String) {
        httpBody.appendString(textFormField(named: name, value: value))
    }
    
    private func textFormField(named name: String, value: String) -> String {
        var fieldString = "--\(boundary)\r\n"
        fieldString += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"\r\n"
        fieldString += "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"
        fieldString += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n"
        fieldString += "\r\n"
        fieldString += "\(value)\r\n"
        
        return fieldString
    }
    
    
    func addDataField(fieldName: String, fileName: String, data: Data, mimeType: String) {
        httpBody.append(dataFormField(fieldName: fieldName,fileName:fileName,data: data, mimeType: mimeType))
    }
    
    private func dataFormField(fieldName: String,
                               fileName: String,
                               data: Data,
                               mimeType: String) -> Data {
        let fieldData = NSMutableData()
        
        fieldData.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        fieldData.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
        fieldData.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n")
        fieldData.appendString("\r\n")
        fieldData.append(data)
        fieldData.appendString("\r\n")
        return fieldData as Data
    }
    
    func asURLRequest() -> URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        httpBody.appendString("--\(boundary)--")
        request.httpBody = httpBody as Data
        return request
    }
}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            self.append(data)
        }
    }
}


extension URLSession {
    func dataTask(with request: MultipartFormDataRequest,
                  completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)
    -> URLSessionDataTask {
        return dataTask(with: request.asURLRequest(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Use this function to call upload file func

```
func uploadFile(file:Data, fileName: String, fileExtension: String){
    var mimeType = "image/png"
    if fileExtension == "PDF" {
        mimeType = "application/pdf"
    }
    let url = "https://v2.convertapi.com/upload"

    let request = MultipartFormDataRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.addDataField(fieldName:  "file", fileName: fileName, data: file, mimeType: mimeType)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data,urlResponse,error in
        

    }).resume()
}
```

#Resources:

https://www.donnywals.com/uploading-images-and-forms-to-a-server-using-urlsession/
https://orjpap.github.io/swift/http/ios/urlsession/2021/04/26/Multipart-Form-Requests.html

Answer (score 5):

```
public func UPLOADIMG(url: String,parameters: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?,filename:String,image:UIImage, success:((NSDictionary) -> Void)!, failed:((NSDictionary) -> Void)!, errord:((NSError) -> Void)!) {
        var TWITTERFON_FORM_BOUNDARY:String = "AaB03x"
        let url = NSURL(string: url)!
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        var MPboundary:String = "--\(TWITTERFON_FORM_BOUNDARY)"
        var endMPboundary:String = "\(MPboundary)--"
        //convert UIImage to NSData            
        var data:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        var body:NSMutableString = NSMutableString();
        // with other params
        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendFormat("\(MPboundary)\r\n")
                body.appendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendFormat("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }
        // set upload image, name is the key of image 
        body.appendFormat("%@\r\n",MPboundary)
        body.appendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filename)\"; filename=\"pen111.png\"\r\n")
        body.appendFormat("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n")
        var end:String = "\r\n\(endMPboundary)"
        var myRequestData:NSMutableData = NSMutableData();
        myRequestData.appendData(body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        myRequestData.appendData(data)
        myRequestData.appendData(end.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        var content:String = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(TWITTERFON_FORM_BOUNDARY)"
        request.setValue(content, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("\(myRequestData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.HTTPBody = myRequestData
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        //        var conn:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
                errord(error)
                return
            }
            var parseError: NSError?
            let responseObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError)
            if let responseDictionary = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
                success(responseDictionary)
            } else {
            }

        })
        task.resume()

}
```

Comment: same error , do you have any other explanation  ? , and what is this `name` and `filename` here in this line `body.appendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filename)\"; filename=\"pen111.png\"\r\n")` ,  is there any key i use from the php code like form-name or something else in the same line , thanks

Comment: name is the key of image  ,like the attribute called name in input tag(html),it is important,  if you get the upload file in php use `$photo = $_FILES['file']`(thinkphp); you must set the name `file`  ;   filename is the image file name,like "aaaa.png" you can change the name by yourself @Panda

Comment: @jansma Thank you for this comment about the "name" parameter! You helped me understand why a specific API was refusing my data. Cheers.

Comment: @jansma, Can we add URL as a file name?

Comment: @jansma, I want to send one url with the file. How can I send?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest this [repository](https://github.com/davbeck/MultipartForm).
You can add `pod 'MultipartForm'` in the Podfile and then follow the example in the repository's readme:

```
import MultipartForm

let form = MultipartForm(parts: [
MultipartForm.Part(name: "a", value: "1"),
MultipartForm.Part(name: "b", value: "2"),
MultipartForm.Part(name: "c", data: imageData, filename: "3.png", contentType: "image/png"),
])

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue(form.contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: form.bodyData)
task.resume()
```

It supports Swift Package Manager too.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension URLRequest {
    
    mutating func setMultipartFormDataBody(params: [String: (Data, filename: String?)]) {
        
        let boundary = UUID().uuidString
        
        self.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        var body = Data()
        for (key, (data, filename)) in params {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            
            
            if let filename = filename {
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
            }
            else {
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n")
            }
            
            body.append("\r\n")
            body.append(data)
            body.append("\r\n")
        }
        
        body.append("--\(boundary)--")
        self.httpBody = body
    }
    
}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ s: String) {
        self.append(s.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is the `application/octet-stream` as `Conten-Type`, this is usually used when the file type is unknown. Some web frameworks/libraries will reject this content-type if an image is required.

Second, I can't see the post length anywhere, try to add it:

```
body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

// set the content-length
request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks for trying to help , i updated the code with `content-Type` and the `Content-Length` but still got the same error , do you recommend anything else ? and also something that i don't understand is there any key i use from the php code like `form-name` or something else , is this line ok `body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n")` ?

Comment: Yes, name=\"image\" is actually containing the field name you are uploading the image on. So, if in your form you have the image field named 'image-field', you have to write name=\"image-field\"

Answer (score 1):

**I implemented Upload image using Multi-part in Swift 4:**

Here is the code. Please have a look

```
//MARK: Uplaod User Profile Pic
func uploadImageToServerFromApp(nameOfApi : NSString, parameters : NSString, uploadedImage : UIImage, withCurrentTask :RequestType, andDelegate :AnyObject)->Void {
    if self.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        currentTask = withCurrentTask
        let myRequestUrl = NSString(format: "%@%@%@",GlobalConstants.KBaseURL,nameOfApi,parameters)
        let url = (myRequestUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))!
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:url as String)!) as! NSMutableURLRequest
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
        //define the multipart request type
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadedImage)
        if(image_data == nil){
            return
        }
        let body = NSMutableData()
        let fname = "image.png"
        let mimetype = "image/png"
        //define the data post parameter
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(image_data!)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        request.httpBody = body as Data
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                // print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                self.showAlertMessage(title: "App name", message: "Server not responding, please try later")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                // print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                // print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                self.delegate?.internetConnectionFailedIssue()
            }else{
                do {
                    self.responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    // self.Responsedata = data as NSData
                    //self.responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject] as NSDictionary;

                    self.delegate?.responseReceived()
                } catch {
                    //print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    else{
        // print("Internet Connection not Available!")
        self.showAlertMessage(title: "App Name", message: "No Internet Connection..")
    }
}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to set the 'Content-Length' in the headers?

Comment: You can add dear,,.

body.setValue("\(myRequestData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

Comment: Yeah. We must add the “Content-Length”, otherwise multipart doesn’t work 

Answer (score 1):

```
class func postMultiPartdata( postdatadictionary: [AnyHashable: Any], apikey: String, completion: @escaping (Any) -> () ) {

        if Utils().isConnectedToNetwork() == false
        {
            Utils().showMessage("Check internet")
            return
        }

        let strURL = "http://redspark.biz/dropp/api/\(apikey)"

        let url = URL(string: strURL)
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        let body = NSMutableData();
        let boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
        urlRequest.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        for (key, value) in postdatadictionary {

            if(value is Data)
            {
                let  TimeStamp = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"

                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(TimeStamp)\"\r\n".data(using:.utf8)!)
                body.append("field_mobileinfo_image\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files[field_mobileinfo_image]\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

//                var imgData: Data? = nil
//                if let aKey = value as? Data {
//                    imgData = NSData(data: aKey) as Data
//                }

                body.append(value as! Data)

            }
            else
            {
                if let anEncoding = "--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
                if let anEncoding = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
                if let aKey = postdatadictionary[key], let anEncoding = "\(aKey)".data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
                if let anEncoding = "\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
                    body.append(anEncoding)
                }
              }
            }

        if let anEncoding = "--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8) {
            body.append(anEncoding)
        }
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        urlRequest.httpBody = body as Data

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {

                print(error!)
                completion("")
            } else {
                var dictonary:NSDictionary?
                do {
                    dictonary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                    if let myDictionary = dictonary
                    {
                        completion(myDictionary)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    completion(error)
                }
            }

            Utils().HideLoader()

            }.resume()

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

following those answers here is my implementation with a concrete example for video and audio. notice that the boundary between elements has such form **--boundary** while the last boundary is written **--boudary--**.

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://...")!
    let boundary = UUID().uuidString
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "post"
    var data = Data()
    data.addMultiPart(boundary: boundary, name: "metadata", filename: "metadata.json", contentType: "application/json", data: metaData)
    
    let ext = fileUrl.pathExtension.lowercased()
    let isImage = ["jpg","jpeg","png"].contains(ext)
    let contentType = isImage ? "image/\(ext)" : "video/\(ext)"
    let mediaData = try! Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    data.addMultiPart(boundary: boundary, name: "file", filename: fileUrl.lastPathComponent, contentType: contentType, data: mediaData)
    data.addMultiPartEnd(boundary: boundary)
    request.httpBody = data
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    task.resume()


private extension Data {
mutating func addMultiPart(boundary: String, name: String, filename: String, contentType: String, data: Data) {
    print("adding boundary: \(boundary), name: \(name), filename: \(filename), contentType: \(contentType) data length: \(data.count) ")
    self.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    self.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    self.append("Content-Type: \(contentType)\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    self.append(data)
}
mutating func addMultiPartEnd(boundary: String) {
    self.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After looking at all the examples above, came up with a solution. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/msanford1540/e8b6e5e85dd4a79c3f4867ec472fc1c9).

Swift 5.7

Call Site Example

```
func upload(imageData: Data) async throws {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.net/upload") else { return }
    var multipartForm = MultipartFormData()
    multipartForm.addField(named: "Content-Type", value: "image/png")
    multipartForm.addField(named: "file", filename: "profile.png", data: imageData)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url, multipartFormData: multipartForm)
    _ = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
}
```

Code snippet:

```
struct MultipartFormData {
    let boundary: String = UUID().uuidString
    private(set) var httpBody = Data()

    mutating func addField(named name: String, value: String) {
        httpBody.addField("--\(boundary)")
        httpBody.addField("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"")
        httpBody.addField("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1")
        httpBody.addField("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit")
        httpBody.addField(value)
    }

    mutating func addField(named name: String, filename: String, data: Data) {
        httpBody.addField("--\(boundary)")
        httpBody.addField("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(name)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"")
        httpBody.addField(data)
    }
}

extension URLRequest {
    init(url: URL, timeoutInterval: TimeInterval = 60, multipartFormData: MultipartFormData) {
        self.init(url: url, timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
        let boundary = multipartFormData.boundary
        httpMethod = "POST"
        httpShouldHandleCookies = false
        setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        var body = multipartFormData.httpBody
        body.append("--\(boundary)--")
        httpBody = body
    }
}

fileprivate extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
        append(data)
    }

    mutating func addField(_ string: String) {
        append(string)
        append(.httpFieldDelimiter)
    }

    mutating func addField(_ data: Data) {
        append(data)
        append(.httpFieldDelimiter)
    }
}

fileprivate extension String {
    static let httpFieldDelimiter = "\r\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good video and code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GH0yMPvQFU

https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/URLSessionMPFD/blob/master/URLSessionMPFD/ViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

typealias Parameters = [String: String]

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    

    @IBAction func getRequest(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let boundary = generateBoundary()
        
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: nil, media: nil, boundary: boundary)
        request.httpBody = dataBody
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func postRequest(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let parameters = ["name": "MyTestFile123321",
                          "description": "My tutorial test file for MPFD uploads"]
        
        guard let mediaImage = Media(withImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "testImage"), forKey: "image") else { return }
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let boundary = generateBoundary()
        
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Client-ID f65203f7020dddc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media: [mediaImage], boundary: boundary)
        request.httpBody = dataBody
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    
    func generateBoundary() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }
    
    func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {
        
        let lineBreak = "\r\n"
        var body = Data()
        
        if let parameters = params {
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
            }
        }
        
        if let media = media {
            for photo in media {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.filename)\"\(lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append(photo.data)
                body.append(lineBreak)
            }
        }
        
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")
        
        return body
    }
    
}


extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}


struct Media {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data
    let mimeType: String
    
    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "kyleleeheadiconimage234567.jpg"
        
        guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
    
}

struct Media {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data
    let mimeType: String
    
    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "kyleleeheadiconimage234567.jpg"
        
        guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getHeaders(inAuthToken: String = "") -> HTTPHeaders {
    var header : HTTPHeaders = [:]
    header["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(self.token)"
    print(header)
    return header
}
func putRequestWithMultipart(url: String, parameters:[String: Any], completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {        
    let url = "http://3.6.147.149:3000/api/v1/\(url)"
```

//

```
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let temp = value as? String {
                multipartFormData.append(temp.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key )
            }
            if let temp = value as? Int {
                multipartFormData.append("\(temp)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key )
            }
            if let temp = value as? NSArray {
                temp.forEach({ element in
                    let keyObj = key + "[]"
                    if let string = element as? String {
                        multipartFormData.append(string.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    } else
                    if let num = element as? Int {
                        let value = "\(num)"
                        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    }
                })
            }
            if let data = value as? Data {
                 if key == "image" {
                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "\(Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970).png", mimeType: "image/png")
                }
            }
        }
    },
           usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
           to: url,
           method: .put,
           headers: headers
           
    ) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
            
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                        print(json)
                    } catch {
                        print("Something went wrong")
                    }
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).