# How do I upload an image using the POST method without using alamofire in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, httpresponse

I am trying to upload an image using POST method in swift.I have given my entire code here.

**ViewController Class:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
     myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

func myImageUploadRequest(){
    let myurl = NSURL(string: "http://52.32.31.149/devweatherscope/public/user/register")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myurl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let parameter:[String:String] = ["register_type":"normal", "email" :"mavin5623@gmail.com","password":"password","full_name":"mavin","device_type":"ios"]
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //let img:UIImage = UIImage(named: "b1.jpg")!
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((myImageView.image!),1)
    if (imageData == nil ){ return; }
    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameter,filePathkey: "profile_pic",imageDataKey:imageData! ,boundary: boundary)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        print("***response=\(response)")
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("****responsedata=\(responseString!)")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.myImageView.image = nil
        })

    }
    task.resume()
}
func createBodyWithParameters(parameter:[String: String]?, filePathkey:String, imageDataKey: NSData,boundary:String)-> NSData {

    let body = NSMutableData();
    if parameter != nil{
        for (key,value) in parameter!{
            body.appendString("\(boundary)")
            body.appendString("content-Disposition:form-data;name=\"\(key)\r\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")}
    }
    let filename = "b1.jpg"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"
    body.appendString("---\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("content-Disposition: form-data ; name=\(filePathkey);filename=\(filename)\r\n")
    body.appendString("content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    return body
}
func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"

}


@IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
                          myImageUploadRequest()

}

}
 extension NSMutableData{
  func appendString(string: String){
    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,  allowLossyConversion: true)
    appendData(data!)
}
 }
```

**I am getting respose like this..**

```
 ***response=Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc87503bd50> { URL: http://52.32.31.149/devweatherscope/public/user/register } { status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 58;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Wed, 27 Apr 2016 06:32:11 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
"Set-Cookie" = "laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ild5KzM4NTdCRnM3aGM2SmpSSWlFckE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicFUzNUFGRUVUYkc5UlpINW0xM1lDK21YcFZLZTIrZlhIWWp4eG9Tbjc0bmhxUWZlaWJtXC9nZVZYVjRuUTBaN0xIWE52MkxvczBKUTM5aE5vdXd2bzB3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJhZTllZDMyNTU5OGRmOTMyMzgxNTIyNjNjYjdhMDFlZjQzNGI3YzdhZDcyOWE0N2IxNGU5MzliMjMzYTc2N2ZkIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 27-Apr-2016 08:32:30 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly";
} })
 ****responsedata={"status":false,"reason":"register type field is missing"}
```

I have entered all the parameters as

```
  let parameter:[String:String] = ["register_type":"normal", "email" :"mavin5623@gmail.com","password":"password","full_name":"mavin","device_type":"ios"]
```

But the response is showing that the register type is missing.How do I rectify this problem and I want to upload my image successfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image with multipart form-data iOS in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623187/upload-image-with-multipart-form-data-ios-in-swift)

Comment: Did you try testing the web service on some REST client such as Firefox's `RESTClient` and Chrome's `Postman` extension? Are able to get a success there?