# Proper way to send images from iOS app to server

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am capturing image from camera and converting image into base64 format. It takes more time to send images to server. If there is no internet connection, i am storing it into local DB and once i get internet connection, i want to send multiple images to server. What is the best way to send images to server from app.

Comment: Sending image through base64 is not advisable, it takes lot of time to get uploaded. Use Multipart for uploading. Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623187/upload-image-with-multipart-form-data-ios-in-swift

Comment: You can send images by using multipart format.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) ? It supports file upload.

Here is an example for image load:

```
public func requestImage(url: String) -> SignalProducer<UIImage, NetworkError> {
        return SignalProducer { observer, disposable in
            let serializer = Alamofire.Request.dataResponseSerializer()
            Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
                .response(queue: self.queue, responseSerializer: serializer) {
                    response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .Success(let data):
                        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                            observer.sendFailed(.IncorrectDataReturned)
                            return
                        }
                        observer.sendNext(image)
                        observer.sendCompleted()
                    case .Failure(let error):
                        observer.sendFailed(NetworkError(error: error))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this one of the example for [async image load](https://yoichitgy.github.io/post/dependency-injection-in-mvvm-architecture-with-reactivecocoa-part-5-asynchronous-image-load/).

Answer (score -1):

You can make request for multipart as follows and then use that request in your `NSURLSession`

```
 NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

        // configure the request
    NSString *urlString = YOUR_URL;
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // set content type
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //create body
    request.HTTPBody = [self createBodyWithParameters:params paths:@[filePath] fieldName:fieldName boundary:boundary]; //params(NSDictionary) WILL BE YOUR PARAMETERS TO WEB SERVICE

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(long)[request.HTTPBody length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Lenght"];
```

Comment: This question is tagged "swift". Your solution may have value, but is not written in the language requested by OP, so it's off-topic. Please provide an answer in Swift. Thank you.