# Upload image with URLSession

Tags: swift

Trying to upload image to server but didn't succeed, here is my code,
nothing happened, couldn't figure why.
What could be wrong?

```
import Foundation
    
    extension URLRequest {
      
      mutating func setMultipartFormDataBody(params: [String: (Data?, filename: String?)]) {
        
        let boundary = UUID().uuidString
        
        self.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        var body = Data()
        for (key, (data, filename)) in params {
          body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
          
          
          if let filename = filename {
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
          }
          else {
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n")
          }
          
          body.append("\r\n")
          body.append(data ?? Data())
          body.append("\r\n")
        }
        
        body.append("--\(boundary)--")
        self.httpBody = body
      }
      
    }
    
    extension Data {
      mutating func append(_ s: String) {
        self.append(s.data(using: .utf8)!)
      }
    }
```

thats even not posting string to server
added request task but the body ignored, must set the boundry and low level? URLSESSEION is not like ALAMOFIRE?

```
  let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
  
  var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
  request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  request.httpBody = httpBody as Data
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    // handle the response here
  }.resume()
```

Comment: And where is called setMultipartFormDataBody() ? That's only the URL modifications, not URLSession code.

Comment: show us the code you use to call the server, not just the small bit you show. See also a how to present minimal code, 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You don't call `setMultipartFormDataBody()` in your edited question. You even set a new boudary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload image with multipart form-data iOS in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623187/upload-image-with-multipart-form-data-ios-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried that link examples, its work, but does it the correct way for upload? must set boundry and other stuff? is it better use alamofire?

Comment: the first and most popular answer suggests `...No Need to use any library for upload images using multipart request...`. See also this gist:  https://gist.github.com/nnsnodnb/efd4635a6be2be41fdb67135d2dd9257

Comment: "must set boundry and other stuff? is it better use alamofire? " If you use multiform part data, yes, you need the boundaries. Alamofire just does it for you, in its internal code, that's all.

Comment: Ok thank you all for answers