# Swift upload file to PHP server

Tags: php, swift, file-upload

So I'm uploading a file from swift to a PHP server, the POST request arrives as expected with headers and all but I'm unable to get anything out of `$_FILES`. It's just an empty array.

I'm clearly doing something wrong on the Swift side, this is my code:

```
func testUpload(){
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("someTestFile", ofType: "zip")!
    var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://testsite.com/upload")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = "----------ds2Gry67efddagdfsfhsHF"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
    self.uploadFiles(request, data: data)
}

func uploadFiles(request: NSURLRequest, data: NSData) {
    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    var task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data)
    task.resume()
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, I just can't figure out what it is...

Comment: Maybe something to do with contentDisposition?

Comment: have you consider using Alamofire instead?

Comment: see this very good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift

Comment: What type of file are you sending? Are you trying to send anything else with the file? Have you attempted a var_dump of the $_FILE and $_POST arrays?

Comment: @jkaufman It's just a zip file, and not sending anything else apart from some headers, so $_POST is also empty

Comment: First, to ensure that the Swift code truly is the issue, use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to test your PHP script. Simply attempt to send a .zip file to your page and make sure you receive no errors.

Answer (score -1):

POST method ,you need add header application/x-www-form-urlencoded