# Sending Post http request from nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have this json:

> {"myFriends":{"userId":"the user id", "userName":"the user name", "friends":[{"u":"friend user id","n":"friend user name"},{"u":"friend user id","n":"friend user name"}]}}

and I want to send him in post request to the server, this is the current way I am trying to do this:

```
+(NSData *)postDataToUrl:(NSString*)urlString :(NSString*)jsonString
{
    NSData* responseData = nil;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    responseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *bodydata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *req=[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodydata UTF8String] length:[bodydata length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:req];
    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error = nil;
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request     returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"the final output is:%@",responseString);

    return responseData;
}
```

The json string contains the json, but for some reason the server always get nil and return error. How to fix this?

Comment: add the error message to your question

Comment: the error message is coming from the server and the message is only -1

Comment: so the server is responding with 200 OK and a message that says -1? check what their API says about the message -1

Comment: the message -1 means error- the error is that the server is getting nil and not the json that I send

Comment: '    NSString *bodydata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString];' this is obsolete.

Comment: oops.. fixed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly help to tell your server about the content type:

```
[request addValue:@"application/json"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Furthermore: in my own code I use:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[bodydata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

Comment: I checked my own code and found another difference with yours (apart from the fact that I use NSURLSessionTask to fetch the stuff asynchronously). I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sure. I suggest you replace the old NSURLConnection way of posting by the NSURLSession / NSURLSessionTask way, which is asychronous and takes some more work, but in the end is better for user experience. Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362790/convert-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsessionuploadtask-example/31363308#31363308

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for POST request with an NSData parameter:

```
- (void)uploadJSONData:(NSData*)jsonData toPath:(NSString*)urlString {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:kRequestTimeout];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: data];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}
```

This is for an asynchronous request, but it should work just fine for synchronous. The only thing I see you might be missing is the "Content-Length" parameter.

Comment: Uhm, NSURLConnection is deprecated. Please use NSURLSession instead.