# Trying to create a multipart/form-data body and then printing it out but it gives nil as output

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that is supposed to generate a multipart/form-data body for post requests so that I can send an image along with form parameters.

```
class HttpService {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift
    static func createMultipartBody(parameters: [String: String], boundary: String, data: Data, mimeType: String, filename: String) throws -> Data {

        var body = Data()

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.append("\(value)\r\n")
        }

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(data)
        body.append("\r\n")
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

I use this function like this:

```
let urlString = baseUrl + "/api/user"
let url = URL(string: urlString)
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let parameters: [String: String] = ["email": email, "username": username, "password": password]

do {
    let multipartBody = try HttpService.createMultipartBody(parameters: parameters, boundary: boundary, data: imageData, mimeType: "image/jpg", filename: "photo.jpg")
    urlRequest.httpBody = multipartBody

    print(multipartBody)
    print(String(data: multipartBody, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
} catch let error {
    print(error)
    return
}
```

This outputs:

```
51551 bytes
nil
```

So it looks like the data is being generated, but I can't output it as string to see how the format looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's printing `nil` is not the data; it's this:

```
print(String(data: multipartBody, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

The data isn't `nil`; the String is. The problem is that you are pretending this is thing is a UTF8-encoded string. It isn't! It's a bunch of random data bytes. Okay, they're not random, but they are nothing whatever like a UTF8 string. So when you try to convert it to a UTF-8 string, you get nil.

If what you wanted was to see the bytes, then look at the bytes. They are a sequence of small integers. (For example, you might print `Array(multipartBody)` or iterate over the bytes and print each one.) Don't try to treat it as something that it isn't.

(Though, to be honest, I do not at all see what good you think looking at the bytes will do you either; you likely won't understand them in any case.)