# How to upload the image file in php backend in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, image-uploading, swift4

I am using following code, Image does not upload. upload the image file with parameters. i am using post method

```
   let uploadData = NSMutableData()


     if let image = self.imgProfile.image {
                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
      // create upload data to send

         let boundaryConstant = "----------------12345";
                // add image
        uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        uploadData.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        uploadData.append(imageData!)
        uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        request.httpBody = uploadData as Data


    }

   print("uploadadata\(uploadData)")

    let postString:String = "user_id=\(5)&name=\( self.nameTextField.text!)&lastname=\(self.lastnameTextField.text!)&city=\(city)&state=\(state)&country=\(country)&address=\(self.addressTextField.text!)&zipcode=\(zipInt)))&adventure_style=\(self.adventureTextField.text!)&image=\(uploadData)"

    print("postString\(postString)")



  //  let postString = "phone=\(phno!)&password=\(passwordTextField.text!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)
                let status = jsonResult["status"]! as! NSString
                print("status\(status)")



                if status == "0" {
                    let message = jsonResult["message"]! as! String
                    print("message\(message)")


                    self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myActivityIndicator)
                }
                else {
                     print("save successfull")

                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }
    task.resume()

    self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myActivityIndicator)
}
```

I want to upload the image file in my url.During the upload image does not upload the image.when i retrieve image does not display new image. the image how can i upload the image. Please help me!

Comment: You can use almofire for API Request

Comment: No sir now i am not using almofire.

Comment: Thanks for response sir. why this method not upload the image

Comment: you can refer to this link for now. I'll post the working code after trying it my self. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift

Comment: K thankyou sir I will refer