# How to send image to server with other parameters

Tags: swift

I call the POST method like this

```
let parameters = ["empId": "1", "empName": "John"]
guard let url = URL(string: "test.com") else {
    return
}
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
do {
    urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch {

}
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data, let response = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
        print(response)
    }
}.resume()
```

It works. Now I need to additionally send an image to server with type `image/png` with name image. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If I read it correctly, you want to send the image to the server with `Content-Type image/png`, but you also wan't to supply a name?

Comment: @JacobKing I want to send the image to server with parameter name "image"

Comment: @JacobKing I tried `parameters["image"] = data`. I get `Invalid type in JSON write (Foundation.__NSSwiftData)`

Comment: So you can't serialise `Data` directly. You need to encode it in some way. If you're sending it in JSON, it's common to use Base 64.Try setting `parameters["image"] = data.base64EncodedString()`.

Comment: Also be aware that the server needs to expect Base 64. If you control the server code you can obviously facilitate this, else you should check the API docs and see what encoding it's expecting.

Comment: @JacobKing Unfortunately I dont have control to server code. And the API doc doesn't have any information regarding the encoding. In multipart can I send image in image/png format and other parameters in json?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Alamofire**, **ObjectMapper**

These example is send image, string.

```swift
func requestMultipart<T: Mappable>(
  method: HTTPMethod,
  _ URLString: URLConvertible,
  parameters: [String: String]? = nil,
  images: [String: Data],
  encoding: Alamofire.ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
  success: @escaping (T) -> Void,
  failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void
) {
  Alamofire
    .SessionManager
    .default
    .upload(
      multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if !images.isEmpty {
          images.forEach { (data) in
          multipartFormData.append(
            data.value,
            withName: data.key,
            fileName: data.key + ".jpeg",
            mimeType: "image/jpeg"
          )
        }
        parameters?.forEach { (params) in
          multipartFormData.append(
            params.value.data(
              using: String.Encoding.utf8,
              allowLossyConversion: false
            )!,
            withName: params.key
          )
        }
      },
      to: URLString,
      method: method,
      headers: header,
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        // handle
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your backend reads your response, but usually backed services use multipart data

refer below link for multipart data:
[Upload image with parameters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162616/upload-image-with-parameters-in-swift)